# Show that $\gcd(a,b)=d\Rightarrow\gcd(a^2,b^2)=d^2\ $

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility, gcd-and-lcm

Show that if  $\gcd(a,b)=d\Rightarrow\gcd(a^2,b^2)=d^2\ $

$\gcd(a,b)=d\Rightarrow\ d\mid a,b\Rightarrow\ \ d^2\mid a^2,b^2\Rightarrow\ d^2\mid\gcd(a^2,b^2)$.
But to complete  the proof we must show that: $\gcd(a^2,b^2)\mid d^2$
How can I achieve this?

Comment: Also special case of this one: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/524454/how-to-prove-greatest-common-divisor-using-bézouts-lemma.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply, write $a=da'$ and $b=db'$ such that $$\gcd(a', b') =1$$ Hence, $a^2= d^2(a')^2$ and $b^2=d^2(b')^2$.

Since,  $\gcd(a', b') =1$,  $\gcd((a')^2, (b')^2) =1$ and thus $$gcd(a^2, b^2) = d^2\gcd((a')^2, (b')^2) = d^2$$

Comment: And how to be sure that: $\gcd(m,n)=1\Rightarrow\gcd(m^2,n^2)=1$ ?

Comment: @HamidRezaEbrahimi Since $m,n$ are coprime, they have no common prime factor. Hence their squares will also not contain any common prime factors since squaring simply doubles the power of each prime factor and doesn't introduce any new prime factor. Thus their squares are also coprime.

Answer (score 4):

Write $a=da'$ and $b=db'$ with $\gcd(a',b')=1$.

Then
$$
\dfrac{a^2}{b^2}=\dfrac{d^2(a')^2}{d^2(b')^2}=\dfrac{(a')^2}{(b')^2}
$$
which cannot be further reduced.

Answer (score 2):

By dividing $d$ on both sides and using $\gcd(ac,bc)=c\gcd(a,b)$, we may assume that $\gcd(a,b)=d=1$, so you only need to show that if $\gcd(a,b)=1$, then $\gcd(a^2,b^2)=1$. Suppose that $p$ is a prime that divides $a^2$ and $b^2$, then $p$ divides $a$ and $b$, this contradict to the assumption $\gcd(a,b)=1$, so there is no prime divides $a^2$ and $b^2$, it follows that $\gcd(a^2,b^2)=1$.